# Suggestions what I can do with 26 images of the same scene taking in different seasons

Tags: post-processing, picture-samples, artistic, collage

I have 26 copies of a scene taken in different seasons from the same position. They are not all perfectly aligned, but can be aligned manually. Here is 1 copy below

[image]

Can anyone suggest what great things I could do with these pics?

I have tried HDR. They turned out funny. I also have a timeslice in mind like the one below

[image]

Comment: what kind of scene it is? Is it a natural landscape, showing the passing of season, or is it an urban landscape, or what?

Comment: @Francesco Hi! I have updated the question with a pic. Thanks!

Comment: Timelapse is one option. Though rather short (26 frames).

Comment: @DoStuffZ wont that be over in a second? :)

Comment: @MnZ At 26fps it would yes. At 0.5fps it could last almost a whole minute ;)

Comment: @laurencemadill To create an effective timelapse of a scenery like the one in the first picture above of 30sec, how many fps will be good?

Comment: @MnZ Shouldn't that be 26/30 which is about 0,8fps?

Comment: Pick the best one and delete the other 25?

Comment: @YaoBoLu Thnx for that. Olin cant do that..all of them are dearer to me :)

Comment: @MnZ Not really sure, haven't done timelapse, but from ones I've seen you want it moving through images fairly quick, my guess would be somewhere around 20fps, but I'm sure google will have plenty of suggestions for an optimal framerate

Comment: @MnZ You could try tethering your camera to a computer and put the camera on a tripod, even just looking out the window when you're out at work or something, and get it to take a pic every 1min for a few hours, that will give you plenty of frames to experiment with